# How to parse a text file based on the modified BNF form specified in config file, in Java?

Tags: java, regex, bnf

First of all, I am new here, so sorry guys if I do something wrong.
I need to write a parser of text in Java, which parses the input text file based on the modified BNF form specified in the configuration file.
I CAN'T use any of the parsing libraries and libraries for BNF forms.
Basically, the only thing I can use is `Regex`.
But, for me, the biggest problem is how to read that configuration file so I can then use that modified BNF form inside of it. That must be done so it would work for any configuration file so I cannot hardcode for one example.
How should I do that? Any help is appreciated.

This is a simple example of how should that config file look like:

```
<a> ::= regex(^[\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4}$)
```

a represents any expression that matches the specified regex

My output should be an XML file representing the parsing tree of the input text file based on the specified modified BNF form.. So basically any valid email address should be matched with this regex above and then I should write that to XML file..

Comment: @Emma hello there.. I just updated it, hope it will help a little bit..

Comment: Have you though about using regular expressions with named groups to parse the configuration? That would be my first attempt.

Comment: The example shows a single rule in the parse file; is that the case always or would there be more rules with references to each other? Parsing a single rule would need just a Regex; parsing multiple rules means you'll probably need to build a full fledged parser for that format. And that would affect the answers you'd get here also.

Comment: @BrancoMedeiros there is more rules with references to each other.. it is basically a file with BNF notation with addition of the rule i gave above.. but problem is I can't use any libraries for BNF..